Can't build orangefox recovery
I got the error while building ofrp
My device: gta4xlwifi


Run cd /home/runner/work/Action-OFRP-Builder/Action-OFRP-Builder/workspace/fox_11.0

In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:291:

In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:266:

build/make/target/product/base_vendor.mk:82: error: _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/samsung/gta4xlwifi/omni_gta4xlwifi.mk]]: "vendor/omni/config/common.mk" does not exist.

10:44:22 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

Device gta4xlwifi not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from TeamWin Github (http://github.com/TeamWin).

I tried using another device tree but didn't work
